# How to Subclass a UITableViewCell using the existing Xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

What is the proper way to *subclass* an existing *sublass of UITableViewCell* that has an attached Xib file. How do I subclass the UITableViewCell subclass and still use the Xib in the new class?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the same identifier, e.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@“ExistingCellIdentifier"];
     if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@“ExistingCellIdentifier"];
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Hope you find this helpful, please commit if you have any questions, good luck.